# mysql effecient query (select and update)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

I have a table that its structure is as like as follow:

```
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ttype` int(1) DEFAULT '19',
`title` mediumtext,
`tcode` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
`tdate` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`visit` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `tcode` (`tcode`),
KEY `ttype` (`ttype`),
KEY `tdate` (`tdate`)


ENGINE=MyISAM
```

I have two query on x.php same as:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id='10' LIMIT 1
UPDATE  table_name SET visit=visit+1 WHERE id='10' LIMIT 1
```

My first problem is that whether updating 'visit' in table cause reindexing and decreasing performance or not? Note to this point that 'visit' is not key.

Second method may be creating new table that contain 'visit' like as follow:

```
'newid' int(10)  unsigned NOT NULL ,
`visit` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`newid`),

     ENGINE=MyISAM
```

So selecting by

```
SELECT w.*,q.visit FROM table_name w  LEFT JOIN table_name2 q 
ON (w.id=q.newid) WHERE w.id='10' LIMIT 1 

    UPDATE  table_name2 SET visit=visit+1 WHERE newid='10' LIMIT 1
```

Is second method prefered rescpect to first method? Which one would have better performance and would be quick?

Note: all sql queries would be run by **PHP** (mysql_query command). Also I need first table indexes for other queries on other pages.

Comment: If a field is indexed and you change the contents of that field in a record, the index must be udpated. There's unavoidable. However, if that field isn't used in a JOIN or WHERE clause, then the index is most likely not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say your first method is the best, and simplest.  Updating visit will be very fast and no updating of indexes needs to be performed.

I'd prefer the first, and have used that for similar things in the past with no problems.  You can remove the limit clause since id is your primary key you will never have more than 1 result, although the query optimizer probably does this for you.

Answer (score 1):

There was a question someone asked [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013468/mysql-datatype-or-php-code-to-increment-by-1-every-time-a-page-in-my-database-lo/8013565#8013565) to which I responded with a solution you may want to consider as well. When you do 'count' columns you lose the ability to mine the data later. With a transaction table not only can you get 'views' counts, but you can also query for date ranges etc. Sure you will carry the weight of storing potentially hundreds of thousands of rows, but the table is narrow and indices numeric.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see a solution on the database side... Perhaps you can do it in PHP: If the user has a PHP session, you could, for example, only update the visitor count each 10th time, like:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['count']+=1;
if ($_SESSION['count'] > 10) {
  do_the_function_that_updates_the_count_plus_10();
  $_SESSION['count'] = 0;

}
```

Of course you loose some counts, this way, but perhaps this is not that important?

Comment: It's possible he is doing it in the database b/c he wants the values to persist across multiple sessions.

Comment: Exactly @Digital-Precision I want  the values to persist across multiple sessions.